# IIS Redirect not working for all clients in the intranet

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting, iis-7.5, intranet

Good day.

Faced a strange problem. Setup a rewrite url for our web application. And it works for some users but not for others.

We use MS SERVER 2008R2, IIS 7.5

I suppose that the root of the problem is in our complex intranet infrastructure. Different domains, different proxies and such. Can't even imagine all the parts of it.

Checked headers from browser and with Fiddler. The problem users don't get 301 code (we use permanent redirect) they just get 200.

Can't think of the way to debug the problem or any possible reasons.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it usually hapens not enough info given. My bad. 
I should have said we're using Sharepoint on multiple servers. And the problem was simply in not configuring all servers for redirect.